# Integral Inequality problem and Mean Value Theorem

Tags: integration, inequality

If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\mu\leq f(x) \leq M$, $x\in [a,b]$, prove that

$\frac{\mu}{2}(b-a)^2 \leq \int_a^b\left[\int_a^xf(t)dt\right]dx \leq \frac{M}{2}(b-a)^2$

Is it possible to use mean value theorem on $g(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ to prove the above?

Comment: This probably is much easier than using MVT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One *could* apply the mean-value theorem for integrals:
For each $x$, 
$$
 g(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt = (x-a) f(c_x)
$$
for some $c_x \in (a, x)$, and therefore 
$$(x-a) \mu \le g(x) \le (x-a)M \, .$$
Integrating this relationship over the interval $[a,b]$ gives
the desired result.

But the mean-value theorem is not really needed, just replace $f(t)$
by its upper (resp. lower) bound:
$$
\int_a^b\left[\int_a^xf(t)\,dt\right]dx 
\le \int_a^b\left[\int_a^x M \,dt\right]dx =  M \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}
$$